# vue v-for array isn't updating

Tags: vue.js, store, v-for

I am making simple chat App

Input name from index.vue

```
const newUser = {
        id: this.$store.state.user.stateWebSocket.getUniqueID(),
        name: this.username,
        room: this.room,
      };
      this.$store.commit("user/putUser", newUser);
```

Show userList on chat.vue

```
<ul id="users">
            <li v-for="user in userList" :key="user.id">
            {{ user.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Get userList on chat.vue by using computed from store

```
userList() {
      return this.$store.state.user.users;
    },
```

store array users on user.js

```
putUser(state, user) {
      // state.newUser = user;
      // console.log("state newUser: ", state.newUser);
      state.users.push({
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        room: user.room,
      });
      console.log("users array on users.js: ", state.users);
    },


state:{
users: [],
}
```

For example, when first user has joined, I can see first user is on userList

```
 <li v-for="user in userList" :key="user.id">
            {{ user.name }}
          </li>
```

and after Second user has joined, I can see the first user and Second user are on the userList; however It doesn't reflect on the first user's view.
After when I press f5 button(refresh), It shows on the userList.

What I want is to reflect as new user has joined without any refresh.

Comments will be helpful.

Comment: Is userList a method?  If so, invoke it `v-for="user in userList()"`

Comment: @danh it looks like a computed property

Comment: @danh It's computed property sorry!